# Dart Pub runtime error

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub, dart-webui, nuxeo

Hi i am using the pub to install an application nuxeo. but while running i got the error like this.

Here is my Error Info:

> Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pub" (in directory "D:\nuxeotest\nuxeo\addons\nuxeo-api-playground\src\main\dart"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>   [ERROR] around Ant part ...... @ 4:156 in D:\nuxeotest\nuxeo\addons\nuxeo-api-playground\target\antrun\build-main.xml

Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is `D:\\` a local or network drive?

Comment: Its local drive D:\

Comment: What was the exact command you run and what do you mean with "install an apllication"

Comment: pub install command

Comment: Interesting. Please use and refer to `pub get` in the future. `pub install` only exists for historical reasons and is only an alias for `get`. I had to try it to see it even exists :D I didn't know Nuxeo. Just found that they use `install` there :-/ https://doc.nuxeo.com/corg/installing-dart-and-related-tools/. What does `pub version` print?

Comment: my pub version is 1.22.0

Comment: Why not 1.23.0 as requested in the instructions? I don't expect that to really matter though.

Comment: i have tried that too giving the same error so i tried with downgraded version

Comment: Does the file it complains about actually exist? What is the line 156 in `build-main.xml`?

Comment: this is the data contains on that file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="maven-antrun-" default="main"  >
<target name="main">
  <ant antfile="D:\nuxeotest\nuxeo\addons\nuxeo-api-playground/src/main/dart/build.xml" dir="D:\nuxeotest\nuxeo\addons\nuxeo-api-playground/src/main/dart"></ant>
</target>
</project>

Comment: i have posted teh same in github too here is the link of that issue

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1816

Comment: here is the screenshots full list of errors. https://prnt.sc/ilw7g9  https://prnt.sc/ilw7ro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166141/discussion-between-santoshraju-v-and-gunter-zochbauer).